# React Native StyleSheet optimization

Tags: react-native, optimization

What's the most efficient (and why)?

"Cascading" styles:

```
export function Title({ children, small }) {
  return <Text style={[styles.title, small && styles.small]}>{children}</Text>;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  title: {
    fontFamily: "Roboto",
    fontWeight: "500",
    fontSize: 20
  },
  small: {
    fontSize: 14
  }
});
```

Or unique style:

```
export function Title({ children, small }) {
  return (
    <Text style={small ? styles.titleSmall : styles.title}>{children}</Text>
  );
}

const title = {
  fontFamily: theme.fontFamily,
  fontWeight: "500"
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  title: {
    ...title,
    fontSize: 20
  },
  titleSmall: {
    ...title,
    fontSize: 14
  }
});
```

Note to myself: http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization

Comment: Thanks for the note to self. Time to focus on other things :)

Answer (score 0):

The cascading style is the best one in case of React Native.

> Making a stylesheet from a style object makes it possible to refer to
>   it by ID instead of creating a new style object every time.

And also you can try extracting common components CSS, no matter how simple they seem, you avoid having to define inline styles over and over again. [Here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet) is the note from RN team and medium [link](https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/tips-for-styling-your-react-native-apps-3f61608655eb)

Comment: Hey thanks but Example 2 also makes use of StyleSheet.

Comment: Example 2 can be used as an approach to reduce the number of CSS line you are writing

Comment: Example 1: Surcharging `title` style with new `fontSize` rule. Example 2: No surcharging, `title` XOR `titleSmall`.

Basically I'd like to know if `{[style1, style2, ...]}` is better than `{someUniqueStyle}`

Comment: I guess it's up to the developers and i am not sure which one is better..RN team follows the  first approach